# Why do i need Class Member to Show image on Canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

```
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ImageViewer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        self.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (self.screen_width, 
                        self.screen_height, 0, 0))
```

> putting image on white background

```
       self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white')

       self.canvas.config(height=self.screen_height, 
                 width=self.screen_height, highlightthickness=0)
       self.canvas.pack()
```

> If i try to use variable `image_tk` instead of `self.Image_tk` it doesn't show image

```
    def show_image(self):
        image = Image.open("./image1.jpg")

        image_width, image_height = image.size

        window_width = int(self.canvas['width'])
        window_height = int(self.canvas['height'])
        window_centre_x = window_width / 2
        window_centre_y = window_height / 2

        if image_width > window_width or image_height > window_height:

            image.thumbnail((window_width, window_height), 
               Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.canvas.create_image(window_centre_x, window_centre_y, 
                image=self.image_tk, anchor=tk.CENTER, tag='i')
        else:
            scale_x = float(window_width) / image_width
            scale_y = float(window_height) / image_height

            if scale_x > scale_y:
               scale = scale_y
            else:
               scale = scale_x

            scaled_width = int(image_width * scale)
            scaled_height = int(image_height * scale)

            image = image.resize((scaled_width, scaled_height), 
                           Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            self.canvas.create_image(window_centre_x, window_centre_y, 
                 image=self.image_tk, anchor=tk.CENTER, tag='i')

img = ImageViewer()
img.show_image()
img.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am very new to python, so please don't mind my coding style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you just use `image_tk` on its own, Python will catch it in garbage collection and remove it. To prevent this from happening, i.e. actually have the image show, you have to bind it to something more permanent which isn't caught in garbage collection. One of the ways to do this is within a class, by referencing `self`.

So, it is not the actual class that enables the image to show, but the fact that when 'attached' to `self` in your class, it is not cleared by Python, therefore letting it appear.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I am not wrong, anything that has to be shown on canvas should be attached to self?

Comment: @codetolive It is only images which get garbage collected in this manner, other canvas objects (Ovals, rectangles, polygons...) do not need to be attached to self to be visible.